# Import of Solution Fails Without Error Message in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

We are trying to import a solution from our Sandbox environment to our DEV environment. When we import the solution into DEV, the system shows the Import in Progress window, but eventually it stops. It states that the import of the solution failed, but in the grid below (which shows the solution components), the Status column does not show any errors.
i have downloaded the XML error log file but log file contains no more messages other than "The import failed. For more information, see the related error messages".What should i do in this scenario?.

Comment: Have you checked server-side logs?

Comment: Check the second Sheet from the error details, usually there you can find more information

Answer (score 2):

We have faced the same issue when there is no space in C drive on our server.
Please check.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a conflict between the two systems which is causing the import of the solution to error out.

The best way to resolve this is to turn on trace logging on the dev server. See below.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699694.aspx#BKMKserver_level_tracing

Then try to import the solution. Once the import has failed, open the log file and check what is causing the conflict.